# Extra } or forgotten $ with biblatex and biber

Tags: biblatex, errors, biber

I'm relatively baffled by the behavior of the following MWE. As far as I can tell, there is nothing wrong with the `.bib` entries. However, trying to compile this document (biblatex v3.3 and biber v2.4) results in the following error:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
<recently read> }

l.42 

?
```

If you make the relevant changes to use `natbib` instead, the MWE compiles just fine.

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = arara
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: no }
% arara: biber
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: yes }

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{belletti1988,
    Author = {Belletti, Adriana and Rizzi, Luigi},
    Doi = {10.1007/BF00133902},
    Journal = {Natural Language \& Linguistic Theory},
    Month = {August},
    Number = {3},
    Pages = {291--352},
    Title = {Psych-Verbs and $\theta$-Theory},
    Volume = {6},
    Year = {1988}}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel} 

\usepackage{csquotes} 

\usepackage
  [
    style=apa,
    backend=biber
  ]
  {biblatex}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\textcite{belletti1988}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The resulting `.bbl` file looks fine, as far as I can tell, which leads me to think it's a problem with `biblatex`, but I'm really not sure. Here's the resulting `.bbl` file:

```
% $ biblatex auxiliary file $
% $ biblatex bbl format version 2.6 $
% Do not modify the above lines!
%
% This is an auxiliary file used by the 'biblatex' package.
% This file may safely be deleted. It will be recreated by
% biber as required.
%
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{ver@biblatex.sty}
  {\@latex@error
     {Missing 'biblatex' package}
     {The bibliography requires the 'biblatex' package.}
      \aftergroup\endinput}
  {}
\endgroup


\refsection{0}
  \sortlist[entry]{apa/global}
    \entry{belletti1988}{article}{}
      \name{author}{2}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=2c14abe3cc130a5e92d3a9be58ce2a7a}{%
           family={Belletti},
           family_i={B\bibinitperiod},
           given={Adriana},
           given_i={A\bibinitperiod}}}%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=3a9997806c8053ebfb136c367b21844b}{%
           family={Rizzi},
           family_i={R\bibinitperiod},
           given={Luigi},
           given_i={L\bibinitperiod}}}%
      }
      \strng{namehash}{fdc76b94e4c47018bee5a5282eb818bb}
      \strng{fullhash}{fdc76b94e4c47018bee5a5282eb818bb}
      \field{sortinit}{B}
      \field{sortinithash}{4ecbea03efd0532989d3836d1a048c32}
      \field{labelyear}{1988}
      \field{labelmonth}{08}
      \field{datelabelsource}{year}
      \field{labelnamesource}{author}
      \field{labeltitlesource}{title}
      \field{journaltitle}{Natural Language \& Linguistic Theory}
      \field{month}{08}
      \field{number}{3}
      \field{title}{Psych-Verbs and $\theta$-Theory}
      \field{volume}{6}
      \field{year}{1988}
      \field{pages}{291\bibrangedash 352}
      \range{pages}{62}
      \verb{doi}
      \verb 10.1007/BF00133902
      \endverb
    \endentry
  \endsortlist
\endrefsection
\endinput
```

Most interestingly, if you wrap `$\theta$` in braces, everything works fine, *e.g.*:

```
    Title = {Psych-Verbs and {$\theta$}-Theory},
```

As far as I know, this is not something that has ever been required with `biblatex` and Biber. Am I incorrect, or is this a bug?

Comment: What's it putting in the `.bbl`? Is it a Biber issue or a Biblatex one?

Comment: @cfr Just posted some updates that hopefully clarify things, though I'm about to head to bed. Good night! `:)`

Comment: The issue has to do with the `\MakeSentenceCase` macro, it can be reproduced with the standard styles and `\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase{#1}}`.

Comment: It works fine if you protect the math with a brace: `Title = {Psych-Verbs and {$\theta$}-Theory},` (this is the recommended method to protect unusual input from \MakeSentenceCase, see the docu).

Comment: Sorry didn't see that you actually had already found the braces. As the documentation says: \MakeSentenceCase "support the traditional BibTeX convention for bib files that anything wrapped in a pair of curly braces is not modified when changing the case." and shows some example how to use it in case you don't want it to kick in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The definition of `\MakeSentenceCase` needs to allow for math mode. A possible fix is

```
\makeatletter
\def\blx@mksc@init{%
  \blx@mkcp@init
  \def\blx@mkcp@nil{\noexpand\blx@mkcp@nil\noexpand}%
  \def\i{\blx@mkcp@nil\i}\def\j{\blx@mkcp@nil\j}%
  \def\do##1{%
    \ifx##1\relax
    \else
      \def##1{\blx@mkcp@nil##1}%
      \expandafter\do
    \fi}%
  \expandafter\do\@uclclist\relax
  \let\(=$\let\)=$}

\def\blx@mksc@eval{%
  \ifx\@let@token\blx@mksc@end
    \expandafter\blx@mksc@end
  \fi
  \ifx\@let@token\bgroup
    \expandafter\blx@mksc@group
  \fi
  \ifx\@let@token\@sptoken
    \expandafter\blx@mksc@space
  \fi
  \ifx\@let@token\blx@mkcp@nil
    \expandafter\blx@mksc@getone
  \fi
  \ifx\@let@token\blx@mkcp@iec
    \expandafter\blx@mksc@getiec
  \fi
  \ifx\@let@token\blx@mkcp@bbl
    \expandafter\blx@mksc@gettwo
  \fi
  \ifx\@let@token\blx@mkcp@sgl
    \expandafter\blx@mksc@gettwo
  \fi
  \ifx\@let@token\blx@mkcp@dbl
    \expandafter\blx@mksc@getthree
  \fi
  \ifx\@let@token$%
    \expandafter\blx@mksc@getmath
  \fi
  \if\noexpand\@let@token\relax
    \expandafter\blx@mksc@cs
  \fi
  \blx@mksc@other}

\def\blx@mksc@getmath#1\blx@mksc@other$#2${\blx@mksc@other{{$#2$}}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Do you think this is robust enough to go into the next `biblatex` release?

Comment: Thanks Joseph! `:)` It would be nice if this could make it into a `biblatex` release at some point, as this seems like a case that `biblatex` should be able to handle.

Comment: Was just curious if this ever made it into a `biblatex` release or if it ever will? I still seem to be having this problem (CC: @PLK).