# Problem with latest BibLaTeX release?

Tags: biblatex

[The bib file from my biblatex-abnt style](https://github.com/abntex/biblatex-abnt/blob/master/bibtex/bib/biblatex-abnt/NBR6023-2002.bib) won't compile properly since I updated BibLaTeX to the latest version.

ABNT's rules are terrible and very inconsistent, so I do a lot of weird stuff in that file to try to replicate them.

Here's one example that doesn't work anymore:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{alves1995,
      author    = {Roque {\relax de\nopunct} Brito Alves},
      title     = {Ciência criminal},
      location  = {Rio de Janeiro},
      publisher = {Forense},
      date      = {1995},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I can work around this particular example in other ways, but there are others, and I'm not sure what they have in common. Maybe the use of groups within entries? But sometimes that works. I don't know...

Also maybe the problem is related to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431932/biblatex-error-in-parsing-title-with-math) somehow?

Comment: This has nothing to do with https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/431932/35864, it is the same problem as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425947/35864 and the linked issues. While the issue in the second question linked will be gone in Biber 2.12 I think that your issue will not be resolved, you'll have to find a different way to get the output you want.

Comment: @moewe Ah! Ok then. I can work around this case already. Another example I was having trouble with was using \mkbibacro within extra braces in the author field; I assume that’ll be fixed along with italics (from the question you linked)? If there are other cases I’ll ask more specific questions then. Thank you!

Comment: In that case an answer that shows the work-around may help future visitors. The general rule with Biber is to avoid braces and macros in name fields as far as possible. Because Biber needs to convert macros to UTF-8 characters for sorting, things can go wrong if braces and macros are used for different purposes.

Comment: @moewe Alright, I'm still working on it, but I'll post an answer here soon. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Did you find an answer? If so would you mind writing it up for benefit of other people with a similar problem?

Comment: @moewe In my case I was able to just leave that out, that's why I didn't update this question. But that first solution came from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/308625/102699), and I think [the answer about using biblatexml](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/308761/102699) should still work, although it's a little cumbersome. I don't know if there are any other ways to deal with this. But I think that question would be a better place for any updates, right?

Comment: `author = {family=Pinto, given=Carlos de Souza Carvalho, given-i=C {de\nopunct} S C}` works but is inconvenient.

Comment: @moewe Ah, that last option is great! I don't know about this question though. I think it would make more sense to add your last suggestion to that previous question, which is about the issue with the name *per se*, and close this as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425947/35864, which is about the same issue with BibLaTeX 3.11 (which is really what I wanted to know here). Should I do that?

Comment: I'll add the suggestion to the other question and you can close your question here.